# Gradle and plugin extension closure order of execution

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures, gradle-plugin

I have 3 plugins 'A', 'B' and 'C'. Plugin 'A' includes plugin 'B' with:

```
project.getPlugins().apply(B.class);
```

Plugin 'B' includes plugin 'C' with:

```
project.getPlugins().apply(C.class);
```

To summarize, the dependencies are: A > B > C

Plugin 'A' has a custom task 'T_A', and a custom extension 'E_A'. Plugin 'C' has a custom extension 'E_C'.

When I use the following `build.gradle` and execute `gradlew T_A`, everything is working as expected, that means the properties are set before T_A gets executed:

```
plugins {
  id 'A'
}

E_A {
  prop_a = 'hello'
}

E_C {
  prop_c = 'world'
}
```

BUT, with the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'A'
}

E_C {
  prop_c = 'world'
}

E_A {
  prop_a = 'hello'
}
```

... then, prop_a won't be set before the task gets executed.

I'm stuck and really don't get why might be wrong.

Are the order of extension's closures within the `build.gradle` file important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration phase, when your apply functions are called some **values are not guaranteed to be set**. So order does matter, but it's a bad practice to rely on it. Complex extensions, such as NamedDomainObjectContainer are always lazily configured.

Firstly you could use [Property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html) in your tasks, their values are set once they're required. This is the preferred way because it minimizes task configuration, but it can get very confusing, a guide showing how to use properties: [Lazy Configuration: connecting properties together](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#connecting_properties_together) Although it uses Groovy, it should be easy to translate into Java.

There's also another solution, which is to add a post evaluation listener. It's called once all the plugins and extensions are configured, but this can get messy if multiple plugins are configuring the same tasks. See this thread discussing [project afterEvaluate usage](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/is-project-afterevaluate-the-proper-way-for-gradle-plugin-to-dynamically-create-default-tasks/31349). On a sidenote some official Gradle plugins still configure tasks by value.

```
class PluginA implements Plugin<Project> {
    ExtensionA a;
    public void apply(Project project) {
        a = project.getExtension().create("E_A", ExtensionA.class);
        project.getTasks().register("T_A");   //prop_a may not be set here
        project.getTasks().findByName("T_A").doLast(t -> System.out.println(a.prop_a));
        project.afterEvaluate(p -> 
            //prop_a will be set here
            p.getTasks().findByName("T_A").doLast(t -> System.out.println(a.prop_a));
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously you could make this a lot cleaner.

I recommend you play around with listeners to get a better sense of the Gradle lifecycle.

Comment: Gradle team tries hard to find replacement for `project.afterEvaluate`. Still at the moment of v6.x we cannot get rid of `project.afterEvaluate` ))